# My discord bot doesnt want to be online, even though the code is ok

Tags: node.js, express, discord.js

I'm just writing some code for my discord bot, it's a meme command that requests. I want to see if the command actally worked, I restarted the bot. When I see the console, it doesn't show the ready message when the bot is ready.

It seems like it doesn't want to log into the bot.

```js
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const Database = require("easy-json-database");
const app = require('express')()

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
    ]
});

const db = new Database("./some-database.json", {
    snapshots: {
        enabled: true,
        interval: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        folder: './backups/'
    }
});

client.db = db

client.once(Events.ClientReady, (c) => {
    console.log(`Bot ${c.user.tag} ready`)
})

client.commands = []

require('./commands')(client)

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    require("./events/messageCreate.js")(client, message)
})

client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
    require("./events/interactionCreate.js")(client, interaction)
})

client.login(token)

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("indicator for on server ok ok")
})

app.listen(5042, () => {
    console.log("Server ready")
})
```

I tried restarting the server over and over again, the doesn't want to be online.

I tried resetting the token and putting the new token in config.json (place where i actually save token), it didn't work.

I tried to ask ChatGPT, it didn't come up with an answer.

Comment: Not entirely sure if this is the issue, but I'd change the `client.once(Events.ClientReady)` to something like `client.on('ready', async () => {...}` just to see if it makes a difference.